# Theme dependent resources in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way to use theme dependent strings and drawables in Jetpack Compose? In xml-based layouts, it could be done using attributes and themes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own local variable, something like this:

```kotlin
data class AppResources(
    @DrawableRes val someDrawable: Int,
    @StringRes val someString: Int,
)

val LocalAppResources = staticCompositionLocalOf<AppResources> {
    error("CompositionLocal LocalAppResources not present")
}
```

Provide needed values in your theme:

```kotlin
val LightAppResources = AppResources(
    someDrawable = R.drawable.drawable_light,
    someString = R.string.text_light
)

val DarkAppResources = AppResources(
    someDrawable = R.drawable.drawable_dark,
    someString = R.string.text_dark
)

@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkThemeColors
    } else {
        LightThemeColors
    }
    val appResources = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkAppResources
    } else {
        LightAppResources
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = shapes,
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalAppResources provides appResources,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in your app like this:

```kotlin
Image(
    painterResource(id = LocalAppResources.current.someDrawable),
    "..."
)
Text(
    stringResource(id = LocalAppResources.current.someString)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to internationalize them? you could just create references in your theme object.

Or make an custom strings class that you can load when you create your theme. i.e. just pass in the result of stringResource(R.string.xxx,...)

Themes are more functional so shouldn't be hard to do it.

Comment: Could you give any example for the same, how to create reference in theme object?

Comment: Actually you could just make a HashMap<Theme, ThemeStrings> (so keyed on theme) and the string object can just hold the integer references for the string you want to vary e.g. class ThemeStrings(val title:Int) so in your fun AppTheme you build the ThemeStrings and add it to the HashMap. So the hashmap can be in  a companion object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).