# Is it possible to use gradient in compose theme colors?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme

I use a gradient for my app background using a box at the moment.

However I recently found out about appTheme in compose and was wondering if there was a way to get this to work to substitute the box that I currently have,

```
private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
   primary = Purple500,
   primaryVariant = Purple700,
   secondary = Teal200,
   onBackground = Color.Black,
   background = Brush.linearGradient( //this right here
       colors = listOf(
           Color.Red,
           Color.White,
       ),
       start = Offset(0f, 0f),
       end = Offset(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY),
   ),
   onSurface = Color.Black
)
```

I am aware that background should accept a type color and that here I am trying to pass it a type brush which is why it does not work.
I am asking if there is another way to get to the behavior I want using themes?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69259272/3585796) on how you can create your own items to be used around the app like theme. If you're asking to change background to gradient of all components, which are using `MaterialTheme.colors.background`, it's not possible.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: yes, what I wanted was not possible, but the SO question that @PhilipDukhov added above worked well enough for my use case.