# How to set a custom Context in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have run into an issue with Jetpack Compose. In my application's old classes (activity and fragment) I am using a custom `Context` wrapper for my custom `Resources` wrapper. This is because string resources values are downloaded from a server; the Strings resource files do contain string IDs, their values are empty and are replaced by the server's values.

In activities and fragments I can simply replace the context in `getContext()` or `attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?)` methods, but how do I do this in Jetpack Compose?

Jetpack Compose does have these `Context` methods: `LocalConfiguration.current` and `LocalContext.current`. I love how straightforward this is, but I was not able to find where this Context object is inited. At first, I thought it was in the parent Activity in `attachBaseContext()` method when I set content, but this code does not seem to be useful:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyComposeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {
            MyComposeActivityScreen()
        }
    }
}

override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    val language = Locale(Utils.getLanguage(newBase))
    super.attachBaseContext(MyCustomContextWrapper.wrap(MyCustomResourcesContextWrapper(newBase), language))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try specifying the context manually with [`CompositionLocalProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#CompositionLocalProvider(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0)):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    updateComposeView(this)
}

override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    updateComposeView(newBase ?: this)
}

fun updateComposeView(context: Context) {
    setContent {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalContext provides context
        ) {
            ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {
                MyComposeActivityScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also a more Compose way to solve the original problem is to create your own string holder, something like `LocalStrings`, kind of as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256686/theme-dependent-resources-in-compose/69259272#69259272).