# Why is viewModel() used in a composabe and viewModels() in an activity or fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

[In this link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel) it is instructed to use `viewModel()` in any composable and in an activity, we will get the same object while calling `viewModel()`. Although it is instructed to use `viewModel()` inside a composable, I was able to use it in `setContent{}` (outside of any composable) also.

[In this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement) it is instructed to use `viewModels()` in an activity or a fragment to get the object of a class that extends `ViewModel`.

In both of the cases, we are getting an object of a class that extends `ViewModel`. So, why do we need to use two different approaches (`viewModel()` and `viewModels()`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask if you can use only `viewModel` without `viewModels` in Compose, the answer is yes. But in some cases it is more convenient to use both of them.

[`viewModels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/package-summary#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).viewModels(kotlin.Function0)) belongs to the `androidx.activity` package, is an extension to `ComponentActivity`, and has nothing to do with Compose. It was used in view-based Android and can still be used with Compose when you need to initialize or update your view model with some activity-specific callbacks.

In turn, [`viewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#viewmodel) is part of Compose and allows you to easily create/access a view model from any Composable.

You can call it directly inside `setContent` since it already belongs to the composable scope, but you would not be as comfortable calling it anywhere else in the activity, such as in `onActivityResult`(I know it's deprecated, it's just an example). You can still do it as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69812413/3585796), but in some cases `viewModels` may be easier to use.