# How to replace, overwrite or change defined composables

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-styles

I'm new to android compose and I think I understood the general idea. Instead of defining my UI in an XML file, I basically "write code" that describes my UI.
However, in my XML files, I could design a layout and define and apply a style to it.
When I did that in a library, I could implement that library in multiple apps. Every app could overwrite and change the applied style, by simply recreating that particular style in their own project and giving it the same name.

For example, my library could implement the style `Button` like this:

```
<style name="Button">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10pt</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">48dp</item>
    </style>
```

When I use Views/Activities from my library in my app, they would have that style. But if I wanted to change a few values, I could simply create a new style in my app scope like this:

```
<style name="Button">
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item> <!-- changed value -->
        <item name="android:textSize">10pt</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> <!-- changed value -->
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">32dp</item> <!-- changed value -->
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">0dp</item> <!-- changed value -->
    </style>
```

This style would now automatically overwrite the old one from the library and change all Views/Activities accordingly.

I used this to change things like colors, sizes, margins and some other things.
With composables, this doesn't seem to work.

So to clarify, what I want to do is:

- Create basic composables `X`, `Y`, `Z` in my library `LIB`
- Create multiple larger, more complex composables `C1`, `C2`, `C3`... using `X`, `Y`, `Z`
- Have my app `APP` implement `LIB` and use `C1`, `C2`, `C3`
- Within `APP`, change colors, sizes, etc. of `X`, `Y`, `Z` so that they change in `C1`, `C2`, `C3`

In `LIB`, I created a simple composable `LoginRegisterDestination` (`C1`). It uses `PrimaryButton` (`X`) and that uses `PrimaryButtonText` (`Y`).

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun LoginRegisterDestination() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background, modifier= Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom) {
            PrimaryButton(buttonText = "Login") {
                Toast.makeText(context, "MY TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PrimaryButton(buttonText: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(1f),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.primary)),
        onClick = onClick)
    {
        PrimaryButtonText(text = buttonText)
    }
}

@Composable
fun PrimaryButtonText(text: String) {
    Text(text = text)
}
```

In my `APP`, I tried to overwrite `PrimaryButtonText` and change its color by trying the same thing I would do with styles:

```
@Composable
fun PrimaryButtonText(text: String) {
    Text(text = text, color = Color.Magenta)
}
```

But that obviously doesn't and shouldn't work. It simply created a new composable and left the old one as it was, which seems like the right thing to do anyway.

I know that I could basically "rebuild" the `C1`, `C2` and `C3` in my project and just "inject" the composable elements from the library where they need to go and modify everything else. However, since `C1`, `C2` and `C3` are somewhat complex structures and there is many of them and I want to modify their base elements like e.g. buttons, labels, etc. that would basically mean rebuilding 95% of the whole library.

Is there a way for me to achieve something like the overwriting of styles in resource files, but for composables? Or at least apply new themes/colors to my library elements within the projects that use them?

Comment: Examine `Button` source code: it has `ButtonColors` parameter, with different default values for different elements, like `buttonColors`, `outlinedButtonColors`, `textButtonColors`, etc. And in each case you can specify your own color on demand.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov That explains how I can color a button, but how does that help me overwrite it? Will I have to "carry" each elements possible parameters in the parameters of each element that uses them? Because that would get out of control pretty quick. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: You're already using `ButtonDefaults.buttonColors`, if you pass `contentColor` there it'll effect any `Text` inside (without explicitly specified color). But the `PrimaryButton` itself will need to have a parameter.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Dont I then have to pass that parameter everywhere the button is used? Which means I would have to pass that from my most "top level" object all the way down to the button, as I described in my last comment? Or is it possible to alter those colors "from outside"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you wanna provide this button color for some composable scope same as you do with theme, you can create your own local variable which you'll be able to provide. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256686/theme-dependent-resources-in-compose/69259272#69259272) to get the idea.