# How to do themeing in Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, android-jetpack

I have a requirement to create an application in the below structure

- Theme 1

  - Light version

    - Icons & Images
    - Color
  - Dark version

    - Icons & Images
    - Color
  - Font
  - String
- Theme 2

  - Light version

    - Icons & Images
    - Color
  - Dark version

    - Icons & Images
    - Color
  - Font
  - String

and while building the application ( apk ), I can just change the themeType to ThemeOne/ThemeTwo and the application builds for that theme. I don't want to change this theme inside every activity/fragment.

for practical example:
for banking apps, the applications will be developed once.

my themes are below

- IciciTheme
- AxisTheme
- SbiTheme

and Icici colors and their logos will be inside IciciTheme, the same applies to different themes.
orange is the primary color for ICICI
for the axis, it's kind of purple
for sbi, it's blue.

It's not specifically about primaryColors. Each theme can have around 100 colors

I want to achieve this through Jetpack Compose,
please share your ideas/ thought process of how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you read the [Custom design systems in Compose guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/custom)?

Comment: Using the default compose theme you can configure colors and fonts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256686/theme-dependent-resources-in-compose) on how you can extend it to any other data you may need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this in Android using product flavors.
Answering considering your practical example as reference.
In specific resource folder, we can write specific dark and light theme variations for specific flavors.

You've to declare flavors for all type of variations you want to cover/deliver. please add below code to your build.gradle file which has **android{ }**

```
...
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        icici{

        }
        sbi{

        }
        axis{

        }
    }

    sourceSets.icici{
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'src/icici/res']
    }
    sourceSets.sbi{
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'src/sbi/res']
    }
    sourceSets.axis{
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'src/axis/res']
    }
}
```

This is right way of doing it considering modular way of maintaining code and  future aspect of changes.

Comment: Hi @Shankar Chowdary,
If this solution guides you in solving prob. pls consider accepting as solution. Let us know the learning.