# How to create custom theme in android compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

anyone knows how to create custom theme in compose?

The default material theme have only specific values like:-

- primary
- primaryVariant
- background
- onBackground etc

but i need to have the new values like:-

- cardColor
- onCardColor
- body
- onBody etc

If anyone knows how to create new color palette then please help?

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69259272/3585796)

Comment: but how to implement "color", you are just showing about how to implement "Drawable" and "String" only but i need to help with the "color".

Comment: Just change types of variables to `Color`, the concept is the same